# running programs without session

Tags: windows-services

I run my programs and want them to go on running although i logged off from the system.
Is there a way to do this without windows services?

Here is what i want:
I remote connect to the server, 
I log in to the server, 
I start my program. 
I log off from the server but my program continues to running...

thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "without services"? Do you not want to write a service or are services prohibited at all? What's the reason for the latter?

Comment: Here is the detail. My program is not a windows service.
I remote connect to a server with a user/pass and start my program. Not to stop my program I would not log off windows.
Here is what  i want:
I log in to the server,
I start my program.
I log off from the server but my program continues to running...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I can think of is running your program as a Windows Service .

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with using a service. You could go to the length of creating a 'server' part of the program that runs as a service and a 'client' gui. But I assume you aren't talking about software you developed, but something else.

The other way would be to use Scheduled Tasks, that would run a program even if user isn't logged in, useful for backup scripts etc.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to write your program, and schedule it to run in the scheduler.

It depends if you want it to run constantly, or not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could follow [these instructions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890) to configure your program to run as a service. You will set it's "startup type" to manual so that it will not start each time the operating system starts but instead you log in and start the service manually. Then, when you log off, the service continues running.